# check/uncheck boxes between tables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following sample code:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="first">first thing</td>
  </tr>
</table>  

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="second">second thing</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="third">third thing</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="fourth">fourth thing</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="fifth">fifth thing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to make such that if you uncheck the 'first thing' box, all other boxes uncheck as well (if they were checked).  Also, want to include that if any of the boxes 2 through 5 are checked, then box 1 must be checked as well.

Comment: Classic check all checkboxes script. add change handlers. check state, set  state based on the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck all other boxes when first is unchecked:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    $('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Check the first box upon checking anything in table 2:

```
$('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    $('#first').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/166gv8tc/

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
// by checking first check/unchecks all
$('#first').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    $('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    $('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  }
});

// if any checked check first
$('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $('#first').prop('checked', true);
    }
});

// if all checked check first, if none checked uncheck first
$('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var allchecked = true;
    $('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        console.log('check');
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
            allchecked = false;
        }
    }); 

    if (allchecked) {
        $('#first').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#first').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/go09n70n/1/